# "Unable to generate PDF from Developer Story. Please try again."

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

When I try apply any job, I want generate resume from developer story, and I get error message: "Unable to generate PDF from Developer Story. Please try again.". Same if I try this from developer story page. It says "mistake on our side". Whats wrong?

Comment: Works for me so it must be a user setting or a user issue.

Comment: Investigating, the service that renders PDFs is ungracefully tearing down the HTTP connection...

Comment: I just want know what is wrong and how i can fix it. Maybe my "Developer Story" contain problem data. Or not contain required data. For example.

Comment: I understand but we have no way of diagnosing that until we work out *why* the server is disconnecting when trying to generate your PDF!

Comment: In the mean time, if you absolutely need to get a pdf from your developer story, if using chrome, you can always just go to print, change the destination to "save as pdf" and get it that way.

Comment: @Travis J sadly but "Same if I try this from developer story page". I am using chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after extensive digging it would appear that the problem seems to be all the images in your developer story. Notably the animated GIFs which seem to cause the PDF generator to use excessive RAM and give up halfway through.

That was coupled with an exception being swallowed and the behavior of `PushContentStream` whereby [it terminates the connection](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/10/async-pushstreamcontent.html) because the headers have already been sent (indicating an HTTP OK).

If you remove 3 or 4 of the animated GIFs you should find that a PDF generates just fine. I've tried upgrading our PDF converter to the latest build but it stubbornly refuses to generate a PDF from your story if there are more than a few of the animated GIFs present.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Interesting. I will try your offer and answer later. Anyway thank you.